# php dynamic array in session variable

Tags: php, arrays, session, variables

I'm a little confused with the following part of my script...

The variables $username and $password are coming from POST form and are ok.

```
session_start();

$errors = array();

if (empty($username) === true || empty($password) === true) {
    $errors[] = 'You need to enter a username and password!';
    $_SESSION['Errors'] = $errors;
} else if (user_exists($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'We can\'t find the username! Have you registered?';
    $_SESSION['Errors'] = $errors;
} else if (user_active($username) === false) {
    $errors[] = 'You haven\'t activated your account!';
    $_SESSION['Errors'] = $errors;
}
```

When I try to store any $errors[ ] variables in the session, the only value I find in the session variable is just "Array"...

But when I write the variable $errors (without [ ]) then it works...

How can I add in this case one or multiple dynamically stacked array variables to $_SESSION['Errors']?

It's probably simple, but I couldn't find any solution yet in the Internet.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `print_r` or `var_dump` since it is an array. Using `echo` will just produce `Array`

```
print_r($_SESSION['Errors']); //this
var_dump($_SESSION['Errors']); //or this
```